# Switch on/off logging (e.g. zlog) following dev-mode being DEBUG or RELEASE

Tags: c, logging, release-management

I am writing a small-sized project in ANSI C. I also plan to use a logging system such as [zlog](http://hardysimpson.github.io/zlog/).  However, I do not want the project dependent on zlog at release time and only need it at develop time. What is the right way to switch on/off those logging statement when I switch between DEBUG and RELEASE mode?

For example,  I have a config file which specifies

```
mode = DEBUG | RELEASE
```

When mode = RELEASE, I want all those instructions  in my project source files, such as

```
#include "zlog.h"
```

or

```
zlog_init("init_file")
```

etc. disappears  so the project does not need to link with zlog.

Of course, one can achieve this using a macro to surround every zlog usage, but that seems just awkward and I suppose there are more elegant ways to switch on/off those logging instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a source file which defines all zlog interfaces you referred to and guarded by macro specifying whether it's in DEBUG or RELEASE mode.

For example:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
/* It's RELEASE mode */
int zlog_init(const char *confpath) { return 0; }
int zlog_reload(const char *confpath) { return 0; }
void zlog_fini(void) {}
/* ... */
#endif
```

When DEBUGging, the file is just empty (due to undefined `NDEBUG` macro), and `zlog_*()` links to the real zlog library; when RELEASing, don't link to the real zlog, but link to the no-op functions defined in this dummy source file.